# How can I identify a ClockTrigger to remove?

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers

I want to remove ClockTrigger that runs once at specified time by exact identification not to affect to the other triggers. So I tried to 1) get trigger's date to run from registered triggers and 2) get trigger ID of which is actually running but couldn't find any method. How can I make one of them or both happen?

Comment: You can't get the Id of a trigger currently running. What is your final objective?

Answer (score 1):

This how I display my project triggers:

```
function displayProjectTriggers() {
  var tA=ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
  var html="<style>th,td{border:1px solid black;padding:2px;margin:2px;}</style><table><tr><th>Handler Function</th><th>Trigger Type</th><th>Unique ID</th><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>";
  for(let i=0;i<tA.length;i++) {
    html+=Utilities.formatString('<tr><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td><input type="button" value="Delete" onClick="google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(){google.script.run.displayProjectTriggers();}).deleteTrigger(\'%s\');" /></td></tr>',tA[i].getHandlerFunction(),tA[i].getEventType(),tA[i].getUniqueId(),tA[i].getHandlerFunction());
  }
  html+='</table><br /><input type="button" value="Close" onClick="google.script.host.close();" />';
  var userInterface=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html).setWidth(800);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(userInterface, 'Project Triggers');
}

function deleteTriggerById(id) {
  var triggers=ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
  for (var i=0;i<triggers.length;i++){
    if (id==triggers[i].getUniqueId()){
      ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(triggers[i]);
      break;
    }
  }
}

function deleteTrigger(triggerName){
  var triggers=ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
  for (let i=0;i<triggers.length;i++){
    if (triggerName==triggers[i].getHandlerFunction()){
      ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(triggers[i]);
    }
  }
}
```